# Will there be a novelisation for 'Batman V Superman: Dawn of Justice'?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

The release of [**Batman vs. Superman: Dawn of Justice - Cross Fire: An Original Companion Novel**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0545916305) got me wondering.

Will there be a novelisation for 'Batman V Superman: Dawn of Justice' and if so, who'll be writing it and when will it be released?

Comment: I hope not... The poor trees!

Comment: @Paul - Trees? How very 1997 of you...

Comment: I'm well aware of ebooks, I've just never seen a movie novelization that didn't also come in the dead tree format.

Comment: @Paul - I wouldn't know. I haven't set foot in a bookstore in a decade.

Comment: They have pretty good coffee, you just have to dodge all the racks of stuff to get to it.

Comment: @Paul - Meh. I tend to read e-books on my phone or listen to audiobooks in my car. Coffee is not required

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## If there are plans, no details have been released — not even the author of the companion novel knows.

As you have noted, there is an official *companion* novel to the film, the excellent [***Batman v Superman: Cross Fire***](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0545916305) by Michael Kogge.

Since there seem to be absolutely no details on the web regarding a novelization of the film, I asked Kogge if he knew anything.  From my email to him:

> Some of us were wondering if there is going to be an official novelization of *Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice*. Will there be one, and will you be writing it? (I noticed you wrote the awesome *Cross Fire* companion novel for the movie.)

His response:

> Thanks for the kind words about Cross Fire! As for a novelization, I'm not writing it. Sorry!
>
> -m

I take this to mean that he hasn't been told of a novelization (given the wording of my question to him) — or if he has, he can't tell me.

It is odd for a novelization for a film like this to not be released simultaneously with the film.  However, note that the release date of *BvS* had changed [at least twice](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/Batman-v-Superman-Moving-Away-From-Captain-America-3-Release-Date-66649.html), which may have affected the plans for releasing a novelization.

## UPDATE

I also asked Greg Cox, who wrote the official novelization for the first DCU film, *Man of Steel*.  He said:

> Thanks for your note.  Alas, I was never approached about writing a novelization of BATMAN V SUPERMAN, and, as far as I can tell, there doesn't seem to be a novelization of that movie. Don't know what the story is there.  Maybe they just decided not to do a novelization this time around?
>
> Too bad. I would've had fun writing that.

This really casts doubt on an official novelization for the film.

Comment: +1 for asking Kogge. Now I need to try to get a straight answer from DC :-)

Comment: @Richard : See update.

Comment: @Richard How will you answer these questions? You'll have to watch the movie over and over!

Comment: @Praxis - B*stards. I was looking forward to that one.

Comment: @Richard : It would have been interesting to see a written description of Bruce's vision (the Darkseid preview).  There are also many plot points and character motivations in this particular film that could use the touch of a committed novelist.  :-)

Comment: @Richard : Still no news on this.  You shouldn't accept this answer (not conclusive enough), but asking not one but two authors is gotta be worth something, right?  ;-)

Comment: @praxis - Yes, a masterful answer thus far. They're certainly the two top candidates to do it.